# Adding sequence number to existing rows based on ID and Date in PLSQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, sequence

I want to add a sequence number (`SEQNO`) based on their `REFNO` and `STARTD`.

[image: Old Table]

[image: New Table]

Comment: An Oracle `SEQUENCE`  can only repeat when they hit `MAXVAL`.  Please explain your logic.

Comment: "put on hold as unclear what you're asking"  after two answers have been given.  I'm also under the impression a number of comments have disappeared.  Strange things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin
 For r in (Select t.*,
  row_number() over (partition by refno order by startd) seqno
  From my_table t
  Order by refno, startd) loop
   Update my_table
     set seqno = r.seqno
     where refno = r.refno
       and startd = r.startd;
 End loop;
 Commit;
End;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/484b3/5 for example of row_number.
This pl/sql anonymous block can only handle a limited number of records.

Comment: Almost done but I want to Update my existing column which is SEQNO .. Is this possible? Update PLSQLTABLE set seqno = (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by refno order by startd) seqno from PLSQLTABLE t order by refno,startd ); I tried it but im getting errors.

Comment: You will need to learn a minimum about SQL if you want to update a table. Also, the errors you get clearly explain what you are doing wrong. And much more politely than I could. Select 5 values from x rows and put them in one column?

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. Something like this but im sure I didnt missed any.

Comment: Did you try the pl/sql block?

Comment: Hello, I have tried it but I'm still getting this error. "ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored"

Comment: I fixed the issue now. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Tell me how to correct my answer.

Comment: BEGIN
 For r in (Select t.refno, t.startd, t.empid, row_number() over (partition by t.refno order by t.startd, t.empid) seqno
  From my_table t
  Order by t.refno, t.startd, t.empid) loop
   Update my_table
     set seqno = r.seqno
     where refno = r.refno
       and startd = r.startd
       and empid = r.empid;
 End loop;
 Commit;
END;

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MERGE`:

```
merge 
  into tableX t
  using 
  ( select t.*, 
           row_number() over (partition by refno order by startd) as rn
    from tableX t
  ) r
  on ( t.refno = r.refno and t.startd = r.startd )
when matched
  then update
  set
   seqno = r.rn ;
```

Test in **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d9582a5c727f72a1fd3cc229ce339793)**.

<sup>(I assume that the PK is `(refno, startd)`</sup>